# Sequelize-cli migration still using previously renamed files in addition off new files

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I recently started to work on an old project for my job with Sequelize 4 (first time using Sequelize for me).
I make a mistake in migration file name before a migration, so I renamed this file and then, my migration run the good file AND the old file name, but this files doesn't exist anymore.

[image]

Here you can see that the first '20220131113500-TrConnectionTypeLocale' is the correct file and the second '20220131113510-TrConnectionTypeLocale' (the timestamp changed) is the old one.

I already looked the SequelizeMeta and it doesn't contains the old file, I really don't know what to do.

I'm using Sequelize 4.44.4

Thank you for you help.

Comment: Did you check where exactly Sequelize searches for migration files? Do you have something like `.sequelizerc`?